# MISRA C++:2008 - rule 10-3-1 - definitions of virtual functions along the inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, misra

**tl;dr;** as far as I understand, this rule advocates to not override an already defined method (if not declared pure). So if I am not allowed to override an already defined method, how would one "customise" behaviour in subclasses and why (despite for "readers/reviewers" convenience and prohibiting call by dominance would one want to enforce such a rule?

---

I don't <s>understand</s> get the reason behind the rule `10-3-1` of `Misra C++:2008`, which is about the definitions of virtual functions along the inheritance hierarchy. Unfortunately, I'm probably not allowed to simply paste the content of the rule for copyright reasons, but it looks like follows:

```cpp
class Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() {};
    virtual void baz() = 0;
};

Foo::baz()
{}

class Bar : public Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() {}; // compliant, since foo() is pure virtual in Foo
    virtual void bar() {}; // non-compliant, since bar() already has a definition in Foo
    virtual void baz() {}; // compliant, since baz() indeed already has a definition in Foo but is declared pure
};
```

It states that there *must be **only one definition*** along the inheritance hierarchy for a given virtual member function. Except, the member function is declared pure but does have a definition as well.

The next rule (`10-3-2`) states that overriding member functions must always be preceded by `virtual`, with an example like the following.

```cpp
class Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void bar();
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo(); // compliant, explicit virtual
    void bar(); // non-compliant, since implicit virtual
};
```

Nevertheless, *I don't understand the reason of the rule `10-3-1` (which disallows to "overwrite" an already defined member function if it is not declared pure) **in conjunction with** the rule `10-3-2` (which refers to overwriting with an example violating the previous rule).*

I am aware of the possibility of a deviation record.

I am actually curious 1) what *explicit* reason (despite for "readers/reviewers" convenience - that seems very unsatisfying IMHO) justifies to disallow one of the primary benefits of polymorphic object-oriented design and 2) why the very next rule just showcases a counter example to this rule and 3) how to avoid a deviation record when "customised behaviour" for subclasses is needed.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this for me.

---

I removed the additional footnote question to focus on the actual question.

Comment: Concerning "family", the C++ Standard refers to a virtual function and its overriders. For overloaded functions it's the "overload set".

Comment: There is a general problems with `virtual` methods and overriding non-pure methods: If you override a non-pure method in a derived class do you: (a) need to call the base class method, (b) must not call the base class method; (c) can call the base class method etc?  The only solution is documenting this behaviour/requirement on the bass class method, something every programmer is going to read ;)

Comment: Rule `10-3-2` seems outdated to me; but this is expected from MISRA C++-2008 which predates C++11. It is far better to use `override` semi-keyword for overridden methods instead of repeating `virtual`. True, you can put both, but I feel this as an overkill.

Comment: @RichardCritten if the method must not be called, it can be declared private (but of course be virtual / overridden). Whether it can or must be called by overrides is another topic and indeed shall be documented well. But this does not answer why I am not supposed to override a base class defined method at all. Or am I getting something totally wrong here?

Comment: I updated my question, maybe it is more clear now what I am asking for.

Answer (score 2):

> if I am not allowed to override an already defined method, how would one "customise" behaviour in subclasses?

By overriding exclusively **pure** methods.

Pure methods are your customisation points. Overridden methods are already customised behaviour. Do not re-customise it.

If you find yourself needing to override a concrete virtual function, split the parent class in two. Say you have

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() { ... };
    virtual void bar() { ... };
};
```

and you want to override `foo` and `bar`. Then do this:

```
class AFoo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class Foo : public AFoo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() { ... };
    virtual void bar() { ... };
};

class Bar : public IFoo
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() { ... };
    virtual void bar() { ... };
};
```

(I called the extracted class AFoo (A for abstract) rather than IFoo because it does *not* have to be a pure interface. Other methods that you don't want to override may stay as is in AFoo.)

This is not always as easy as shown, for example if you want to override a method that is 5 inheritance levels deep in the hierarchy. You will have to duplicate massive amounts of code, creatively use multiple inheritance, or rework your design to use more containment and less inheritance. But such is life of a C++ programmer who <s>sells his soul to MISRA</s> works in an industry that enforces coding standards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically your answer confirms my initial guess (I deleted that part of my question to focus on the actual question rather than my own guess). I wrote: `Does this rule 10-3-1 somehow wants to emphasize a rule like Item 33 of Scott Meyers More Effective C++: "Make non-leaf classes abstract"?` - that is exactly what you suggest, so probably it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of my answer will not be satisfying for you . . .

If your software-quality-assurance/functional-safety/cyber-security team, will define this rule in the coding guidelines, then you must follow it.

The static code analysis tools will find it anyway and report it as non compliant. Most probably a ticket will be created. Then, you must resolve the issue.

- Either modify the code
- Make an expert peer code review and give a justification

Since this rule is required, it will most probably be enabled in the ruleset for your static code analysis tool.

And, if you have a 3rd party code audit, it will always be found, and you need to give a justification, why the rule is violated.

All this may be annoying, but better to follow the rules.

---

Next, the rationale.

The rule says:

> There shall be no more than one **definition** of each virtual function on each path through the inheritance hierachy

The rule has been made, so that readers and especially reviewers in the code review phase can be sure that the version of the function that can be executed from any point in the class hierachy is unambiguous. It must be consistent with readers expectation.

And the rule also prevents call by dominance. Please read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(C%2B%2B)) about that.

So, the goal is to immediately "see" which functions will be called, without the need to study all the nitty gritty stuff in the C++ language definition.

The example code in the rule, which is a little bit more than you are showing above, better examples and explanations are given, so that it is possible to get a good understanding.

---

The explanation for rule 10-3-2 is similar:

Make things clear.

The override keyword could also be used nowadays, but has a different intention. It will lead to a compile error, if you think that you are overwriting some function, but have a typo or different signature. I would recommend to use also override.

---

Please note again: Neither "virtual" nor "override" are mandatory. The code will (most probably) work without them.

But if you read the code, then things will be more clear.

So, it is for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of what a "required" MISRA rule "is" - so that part of your answer is not disappointing at all. I also understand, why / how this rule prohibits call by dominance in the particular cases. But as far as I understand, this rule advocates to not override an already defined method (if not declared pure). So if I am not allowed to override an already defined method, how would one "customise" behaviour in subclasses? The only solution in my view would be according to item 33 of "More Efficient C++", i.e. extracting a pure abstract base class. Is this the case here?